# Downloaded file via zend rest is corrupted

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to download a zip file via zend framework. For this purpose I built the following code snippet:

```
function fetchAll($params = []) {
  $file = __DIR__ . '/../../../../htdocs/_downloads/test.zip';
  $response = new Stream();
  $response->setStream(fopen($file, 'rb'));
  $response->setStatusCode(200);
  $response->setStreamName(basename($file));
  $headers = new Headers();
  $headers->addHeaders([
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($file)
  ]);
  $response->setHeaders($headers);
  return $response;
}
```

The code above is part of a rest resource.

Now I downloaded the file twice: Once with WinSCP, once with my REST API. The files I got have exactly the same size on my disk (1,390,687 bytes). The problem is that I can open the zip file downloaded by WinSCP but cannot open the file downloaded via REST. The error message says that the file is corrupted.

Comment: Have a look at both downloaded files to see what the difference between them is... (if they are the same size, the most likely difference will be at the beginning or at the end).

Comment: A function with a relative path (using "up" folders) doesn't seem as flexible as a function should be...

Comment: @altralaser, forgive me if this sounds like a stupid suggestion, but can you open the corrupted zip file if you copy it to another computer? I ran into a similar issue on Windows when automating downloads (I even used WinSCP to test). In my case the file was fine, but Windows was doing something to the file (perhaps flagging it in some way) preventing it from opening. I was never able to resolve the issue.

Comment: just compare sha256 and/or md5 checksum to verify that it's downloading same file or manipulating it.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Had I opened the file, I would have noticed that PHP wrote a warning to stdout, which apparently ended up in the zip file. But thanks anyway for your help!